# ActivityNotFoundExceptionstarted appearing out of nowhere

Tags: android

Before my application was working fine. I just created a new class (within the same package) and also declared it in the manifest, still I get a `ActivityNotFoundException` and sometimes `NoClassDefFoundException`.

**TestActivity.java**

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.order_summary);

    }
}
```

**Activity_NewOrder.java**

```
public class Activity_NewOrder extends Activity
try {
         //Also tried Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_NewOrder.this, TestActivity.class);
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mypackage">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Activity_OrderSummaryNew"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Activity_Login"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Activity_Orders"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Activity_NewOrder"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Activity_OrderHistory"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />

        <activity android:name=".Activities.TestActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: try cleaning build and rebuild your project. It will clear the cache and will generate the activity class again

Comment: `com.example.mypackage.Activities.TestActivity` make path is correct?

Comment: remove .Activities from every `android:name=".Activities.Activity_Orders"` and than clean and run

Comment: if you're using proguard you might be missing the needed rules for this

Comment: I have created a package called Activities, inside it all my activity files are there.

Comment: The path is correct otherwise `Activity_Login -> Activity_Orders -> Activities_NewOrder` wouldn't have worked either

Comment: @thepoosh what rules are you talking about? I have never worked with proguard and hence haven't changed it. they are as generated by Android Studio

Comment: @Artist404 I tried Invalidate caches and restart I ll give clean and rebuild a shot

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks @Artist404

Comment: @GeetChoubey You're welcome :)